# azure amortized cost usagestart and usageend date error while passing it as variable

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, cost-management, azure-billing-api

I am trying to pull azure amortized cost at subscription level but when I pass usage_start_date and usage_end_date in hardcoded way I am able to pull data :
Example : `"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/"+subs+"/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetail?$filter=properties/usageStart eq '2022-05-01' and properties/usageEnd eq '2022-05-31'&metric=AmortizedCost&api-version=2021-10-01"`

But when I am passing start usage and start end date as variable it is throwing error.
API example:

```
f"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subs}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?$filter=properties/usageStart eq {start_date} and properties/usageEnd eq {end_date}&metric=AmortizedCost&api-version=2021-10-01"
```

like :

```
'message': 'Billing Period is not supported in (2019-10-01) API Version for Subscription Scope With Web Direct Offer. Please provide the UsageStart and UsageEnd dates in the $filter key as parameters.'}}

{'error': {'code': '400',
  'message': 'Billing Period is not supported in (2021-10-01) API Version for Subscription Scope With Web Direct Offer. Please provide the UsageStart and UsageEnd dates in the $filter key as parameters. (Request ID: f2d9517e-e438-42b3-865e-df2d5888da62)'}}
```

I have tried many option/combination to pull data by passing date range variable it gave me same error.
I have tried API from this link as well:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/manage-automation#get-usage-details-for-a-scope-during-specific-date-range
```

Can you please guide me what I am doing wrong. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you try surrounding your start/end dates with ticks (e.g., `properties/usageStart eq '{start_date}' and...`)? I suspect there's an error internally since those are missing and that it's trying to fall back to billing period.

Answer (score 2):

Finally this help me

```
not working:
costmanagement_client.usage_details.list( scope=f'/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/', filter=f"properties/usageEnd eq {end_date} and properties/usageStart eq {start_date}")

working:
costmanagement_client.usage_details.list( scope=f'/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/', filter=f"properties/usageEnd eq '{end_date}' and properties/usageStart eq '{start_date}'")
```

just put in quote

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the time along with date

properties/usageStart eq '2022-07-01T00:00:00.0000000Z' and properties/usageEnd eq '2022-07-31T23:59:59.0000000Z'

try this

Comment: No man i tried
{'error': {'code': '400',
  'message': 'Billing Period is not supported in (2021-10-01) API Version for Subscription Scope With Web Direct Offer. Please provide the UsageStart and UsageEnd dates in the $filter key as parameters. }

Comment: any other ideas